# Is there a native function that applies piecewise or() to multiple logical arrays?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Is there a native function that applies piecewise `or()` to multiple (ie. more than 2) logical arrays of possibly unknown number?

For example,

```
TF={};
TF{1}=[0,1,0];
TF{2}=[0,0,1];
TF{3}=[0,0,0];
```

where `TF` may contain more logical arrays of matching dimension and `size(TF,2)` may be greater than 1.

I wish `or(TF{:})` could work but it does not. Is there a native function that can extract the following?

```
>> (TF{1} | TF{2}) | TF{3},
ans = 
    [0,1,1];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [any](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) :

```
result = any(vertcat(TF{:})) ;
```

Comment: Or `any(vertcat(TF{:}), 1)` in case there is a single array in `TF`